# Python: Is it possible to predict the runtime of the code?

Tags: python, runtime, loading

I am processing a large amount of data with around 500 MB and want to know how much time it takes the process to complete.

I found out that it is only possible to implement loading bars in loops.
Why is that so? What is the technical reason behind not knowing how long a code takes to complete in advance?

Comment: In general you can't ([the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). But if your specific program is processing a certain amount of data, you can estimate based on how much it has done so far and how long it took. What is stopping you?

Comment: You don't have to implement loading bars in loops. You can have them anywhere you like. Perhaps a loading bar is the most accurate when it's in a loop, but it's hardly mandatory. You might remember the bad old days when software installs and file downloads would jump from 0% to 99% in seconds, and then hang there for minutes. Those loading bars probably weren't in a loop.

Comment: @khelwood Thank you for this answer. 

This explains the problem. How can I implement a loading bar then for a "normal" top to bottom script without any loops?